# Reverting to the classic Google cache link in search results via userscript

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

I would like to ask if it is possible to bring back the "Cached" link in Google search results (back next to the result title).

So does anyone know of (or if it's possible to make) an extension or userscript that will move the Cache link, widen the search results container and maybe even remove the hover preview thing?

I saw some time ago that there were some userscripts to revert the google theme back to white instead of this new google-plus-marketing gray theme.

My main point, was that I consider the moving of the "Cached" button a huge step backward for the cost of some marketing of a small new feature (the annoying hovered-preview); because frankly, there's no other reason why Google would have tempered with its previously perfect position.

- this is what Google is doing: makes me break flow, move pointer towards an invisible button, hover, move pointer again upward, click on "Cached".
- this is what Google used to do: make me move the pointer just about 10 px from where it naturally sits while reading the result and click on "Cached".

I want the latter back. Even if I have to write a damn userscript or extension myself.

But is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily, someone has already created a userscript that does what you want- it may or may not have been the original asker. Here you go: [Resurrect Google Cache & Related links.](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/114455)
I realize that the asker has probably already solved the problem, I'm just writing this for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

[From LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5851113/how-to-access-google-cache-links-in-googles-new-layout) -

> The cache links have moved into the actual instant preview itself. All
>   you need to do to get a cached version of a page is mouse over the
>   result, hit the little arrow that expands the page preview, and hit
>   the "Cached" link. If you avoided instant previews like I did, you
>   might never have realized this was there.

Bing also shows the link to the cached version of a result page in the Preview that you can go to by hovering over the result & over the arrow that shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome, you can just put `cache:` in the address bar in front of the URL to access the cache.